# console.table() prints weird characters on Git Bash

Tags: javascript, git-bash

```
console.table({ email, password })
```

works fine on vscode's terminal:

[image: good table]

However, when I run the same program on Git Bash, I get this as a table:

[image]

I have tried going

```
Git Bash > Options > Terminal > Type
```

And trying different types, but no luck.